# Pointer Subtraction and an Alternative

Tags: c++, c, pointers

When working with arrays, standard algorithms (in both C and C++) often return pointers to elements.  It is sometimes convenient to have the index of the element, perhaps to index into another array, and I normally get that by subtracting the beginning of the array from the pointer:

```
int arr[100];
int *addressICareAbout = f(arr, 100);
size_t index = addressICareAbout - arr;
```

This always seemed simple and effective enough.  However, it was recently pointed out to me that pointer subtraction actually returns a `ptrdiff_t` and that, in principle, there could be problems if the "`index`" doesn't fit in a `ptrdiff_t`.  I didn't really believe that any implementation would be perverse enough to allow one to *create* such a large arr (and thereby cause such issues), but the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494688/when-exactly-is-a-pointer-difference-defined) admits that that's possible and I've found no evidence to suggest otherwise.  I've therefore resigned myself to this being the case (unless someone can convince me otherwise) and will be careful going forward.  That answer proposes a fairly convoluted method of "safely" getting the index; is there really nothing better?

That said, I'm confused about a possible workaround in C++.  There we have `std::distance`, but is `std::distance(arr, addressICareAbout)` guaranteed to be well-defined?  On the one hand, (the pointer to the first element of) `arr` can be incremented to reach `addressICareAbout` (right?), but on the other hand `std::distance` should return a `ptrdiff_t`.  The iterators for the standard containers can (presumably) have the same issues.

Comment: Yes `std::distance` does exactly what you are describing. For example your pointer arithmetic trick only works with *contiguous* containers, it would fail for `std::list`. On the other hand `std::distance` handles both contiguous and non-contiguous containers, as long as they are ordered.

Comment: Your post is interesting but I can't see a question. Are you asking, "what type should I use to store pointer offsets?". If so, the answer is a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: I have 1.5 questions:
1.0) In C++, can `std::distance` be used "safely" for containers or do I have to worry that the distance might overflow `difference_type`?
0.5) Is the situation in C (working with pointers) _really_ as bad as it seems?

Comment: from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t  _If an array is so large (greater than PTRDIFF_MAX elements, but less than SIZE_MAX bytes), that the difference between two pointers may not be representable as std::ptrdiff_t, the result of subtracting two such pointers is **undefined**._  Hence, great question.

Comment: I saw that reference too, and it seemed plausible (though I've seen bad sample code on that site before).  Would a system allowing that be compliant?  Do such systems even exist?  Is there a "simple" alternative to pointer subtraction that will work in such cases?

Comment: I believe that if the premise is true, it is impossible for the compiler to make it compliant (e.g. on a 16 bit address model, you can't store the possible full "pointer arithmetic range" of -65535..+65535 in a 16 bit word).

Comment: `std::distance(arr, addressICareAbout)` will almost certainly just be `return addressICareAbout - arr;`

Comment: Doesn't the linked question itself provide the workaround? Insert `PTRDIFF_MAX` somewhere into your allocation system to prevent overflow being an option. Yes the *standard* doesn't make the ruling about `PTRDIFF_MAX` being helpful for this, but the implementation would be effectively broken if you couldn't rely on it to give a useful value here.

Comment: Could you add this to your source, `#if PTRDIFF_MAX < SIZE_MAX #error ... #endif` just to see if it is an issue with the specified compiler/target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is extremely unlikely that you will ever have two pointers to the same array where the difference doesn't fit into ptrdiff_t.

On 64 bit implementations, ptrdiff_t is signed 64 bit, so you'd need an array of 8 billion gigabytes. On 32 bit implementations, usually your total address space is limited to 3 GB, 3 1/4 GB if you are lucky (it's address space, not RAM, that counts), so you'd need an array of more than 2 GB which doesn't leave much for anything else. And it is quite possible that malloc will refuse to allocate an array of that size in the first place. Your judgement of course.

While std::distance has advantages, I suspect it has the same theoretical problem as ptrdiff_t, since distances can be positive and negative, and it's probably not a 64 bit type on a 32 bit implementation.

Note that if you can allocate a 3 GB array on a 32 bit implementation, and you have two int* to the first and the last element of that array, I wouldn't be surprised if the pointer difference is calculated incorrectly even though the result fits into ptrdiff_t.

Comment: The difference would be -1gigabyte, which if added to the first address would yield the second (due to arithmetic overflow).

Comment: @RichardHodges: Signed overflow has no guarantees in C++. Prior conversion to unsigned could get you there if you're careful.

Comment: I know that 32 bit compilers can support 64 bit integers (as `long long int`), so in those implementations, `ptrdiff_t` COULD be defined as `long long int`, and it would "just work" (but you have to make sure you use `ptrdiff_t` and NOT just `int`.

Comment: "you'd need an array of more than 2 GB".... No, you'd need an array with more than 2 billion *elements*.  For an array of `int` on a 32-bit system, that means 8 GB, which can't possibly fit in the address space.  The issue can only potentially occur for `sizeof (T) == 1`.

Comment: GCC (and possibly others) will assume that objects occupy no more than half the address space anyway: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-08/msg00221.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround:

Cast both pointers to `uintptr_t`, subtract, and divide by `sizeof (T)` yourself.  This is not precisely portable, but it's guaranteed never to be undefined behavior, and most systems specify integer<->pointer conversion in a way that makes this work.

Really portable (but less efficient) workaround:

Use an alternative base pointer.  If the array is more than `2<<30` elements, then you can legally compute `step = p1 + (2<<30)`, use relational operators to see whether `p2 > step`, and if so, calculate the offset as `(2u << 30) + uintptr_t(distance(step, p2))`  Note that the recursive call may require taking another step.

Comment: Converting to `uintprt_t` is not portable. I've worked on systems (Cray vector systems) where this would not work. On those systems, byte pointers are implemented as 64-bit word pointers with a 3-bit offset stored in the high-order 3 bits; pointer-to-integer conversion just copies the bits. I suspect you're more likely to encounter a system where converting to `uintptr_t` will fail than one where straightforward pointer subtraction will overflow. And I don't know what you mean by "*guaranteed never to be implementation-defined behavior*".

Comment: The standard guarantees that you can convert a `void*` to `uintptr_t` (which might not even exist) and back to `void*`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer. If you perform arithmetic on the `uintptr_t` value, the standard guarantees nothing. The resulting pointer is implementation-defined and may be a trap representation, so just evaluating the pointer has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: But I'm not casting back to a pointer, let alone dereferencing one, there is no undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, you're right, the idea is to compute an integer index. But the index might be meaningless, and *using* it to index into the array could have undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, but you can portably check whether it worked.  `if (index < element_count && p2 == p1 + index)`

Answer (score -2):

> I've found no evidence to suggest otherwise.

Fortunately there is evidence here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

> `std::size_t` can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array). A type whose size cannot be represented by `std::size_t` is ill-formed (since C++14)

Comment: True, `size_t` must be large enough to store the size of `arr`.  But must `ptrdiff_t` be large enough to store any index?

Comment: To clarify, it seems that the subtraction is already undefined if the difference overflows a `ptrdiff_t`, regardless of what type of variable I'd _like_ to assign the result to.

Comment: ah ok, it is conceivable that in a segmented (or paged) memory system you could have address differences larger than than the maximum size of an array.

Comment: The problem isn't "larger than the maximum size of an array". The problem is that ptrdiff_t must handle positive and negative numbers, and you might have an array with a size larger than the largest possible ptrdiff_t (not larger than the largest possible size_t).

Comment: it would still work because of arithmetic overflow. e.g. in a 16-bit memory system, 0xffff - 0x0000 would yield a ptrdiff of -1 (0xffff). Adding -1 to 0x0 would yield address 0xffff

Comment: How does this answer the question? (Hint: it doesn't)

Comment: Overflowing signed types is undefined while casting an unsigned type to a signed type that can't hold the value is implementation defined.  I'd hate to rely on either of these.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in fairness, there is no question to answer.