# stepping an Iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I previously [asked about pointer subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123334/pointer-subtraction-and-an-alternative), concerned that I could have an array with more than `PTRDIFF_MAX` elements, allowing pointer subtraction within the array to possibly overflow.  The consensus seemed to be that there's nothing in the standard to prevent such arrays, though most if not all implementations will likely forbid them.

Now I'm curious about going the opposite direction, specifically for `vector`s.  I *guess* I can add any `size_t` to a pointer provided that I stay within (or go one element past the end of) its array -- at least, I have found nothing to suggest otherwise.  For `vector::iterator`s things seem more complicated (which is unfortunate, given that they're basically intended to be better versions of pointers).  I can index into a `vector` with any `vector::size_type`, but `vector::iterator` arithmetic operators take `vector::difference_type`s, potentially leading to the same problem as above.  This is particularly troublesome because some `vector` functions *require* `vector::iterator`s.

I considered trying to get around this with `advance(it, N)`.  Unfortunately, the specification for this function template seems to be internally inconsistent.  My understanding is that, for nonnegative `N`, this should be equivalent to

```
while(N) {
    ++it;
    --N;
}
```

but that for random access iterators it should be implemented as:

```
it += N;
```

Alas, these are *not equivalent* if `N > numeric_limits<vector::difference_type>::max()`, for in such cases the former will yield a well-defined `vector::iterator` (provided we stay within the `vector`) while the latter may(?) yield undefined behavior.

Am I misunderstanding the standard?  Is there a built-in way to efficiently and safely step `vector::iterator`s?

Comment: `vector::difference_type` is usually a `ptrdiff_t`, which is usually just a signed value of the same bit length as `size_t`. If you're trying to step around `vector`s skipping more than 2 billion elements (2^31+) at a time (on 32 bit systems) and the ridiculous limit (2^63+) (on 64 bit systems), you have bigger problems. Heck, unless it's a `vector` of byte or smaller values, it couldn't actually get that big without using up all your virtual memory space (in practice, it would have to be sub-byte sized most of the time; usually virtual memory addresses are divided 50/50 with kernel space).

Comment: Oh, I agree, it's unlikely I'll find a real system in which this could be a problem.  But does the standard _guarantee_ it never will be a problem?  If not, does the standard provide a solution for dealing with this issue?  And what _is_ the intended functioning of `advance` in such a case?