# why is subtracting an array from lower_bound return a dereferenced value?

Tags: c++

```
  int arr[] = {0, 1, 15, 22, 100, 101, 232, 2323};
  int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  int x = 232;

  auto a = lower_bound(arr, arr + n, x) - arr;
  if (a < n && arr[a] == x) {
    // x found at index a
    cout << x << " is found " << "at index: " << a << endl;
  }
```

lower_bound returns an address of the element but if we subtract - arr from it, it dereferences the pointer. How come that happens?

Comment: Are you asking why `a` results in an index value?

Comment: I'm a little confused. subtracting 2 pointers gives an int. Where do you think anything is getting dereferenced? Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123334 will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr` is an array, and when an array is used in an expression, it can [decay into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).  Since `lower_bound` returns a pointer (that's the iterator type for a raw array), and `arr` decays into a pointer, you are subtracting the address of the found object from the address of the start of the array which gives you the number of elements between them.  There is no dereferencing happening at all.

Comment: It is actually opposite address of the first from address of the found.