# Object size from (begin, end) pointers in strictly conforming C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards, pointer-arithmetic

Suppose I have two pointers to `char` pointing to the beginning, *begin*, and just past the end, *end*, of an array of some kind (as is customary in C++ before ranges, for example). One would expect all I would need to do to calculate the size of said array in bytes would be to compute *end* − *begin*.

However, the latest ISO C standard has the following to say about it (in §6.5.6 paragraph 9, emphasis mine):

> When two pointers are subtracted [...] the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. *If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.*

Equivalent phrasing is present all the way back to ANSI C §6.3.6.

This seems to be a problem, and not an entirely theoretical one, both on systems with 16-bit `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` where one would want to handle arrays of size ≥ 2<sup>15</sup>, and on systems with 32-bit `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` where one does occasinonally want to handle arrays of size ≥ 2<sup>31</sup> (*e.g.* on a 32-bit Windows server running with `/3GB`).

(The first case has been made non-conforming by C99 requiring `ptrdiff_t` to hold values up to at least 2<sup>16</sup> − 1, but that requirement has been [widely ignored](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2808.htm) on embedded systems. The second is somewhat complicated by GCC and Clang in their default configurations [silently miscompiling](https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2016/05/20/objects-larger-than-ptrdiff_max-bytes/) 32-bit code that links to `malloc` succeeding with ≥ 2<sup>31</sup> bytes. But I’d argue that both are still reasonable things to want to do.)

In fact, the inability to calculate the size of an object from a (*begin*, *end*) pair by subtracting was [given by the current editor of the ISO C standard](https://thephd.dev/_vendor/future_cxx/papers/C%20-%20Restartable%20and%20Non-Restartable%20Character%20Functions%20for%20Efficient%20Conversions.html#design-forms-simplify) to avoid adding an API that takes such pairs. (Such APIs are in any case unusual for the C standard library, though, unlike in C++.)

So, *is* there an *O*(1) way to calculate the size of an arbitrarily-sized object given (*begin*, *end*) pointers in a strictly conforming ISO C program? You could always do `size_t size = 0; while (begin++ < end) size++;` as an *O*(*size*) solution, of course, but that seems silly even if a modern optimizing compiler can figure it out.

Comment: [Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495779) has an algorithm that works in logarithmic time, but no proof of impossibility (or otherwise) of a constant-time solution was given.

Comment: On a 64-bit system, this *is* a purely theoretical problem -- just subtract the pointers.  On a 32-bit system, convert the pointers to `uintptr_t` and then to `int64_t` and do the subtraction. On a 16-bit system, convert the pointers to `uintptr_t` and then to `long` and do the subtraction.

Comment: @user3386109 None of that is _strictly conforming_ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conformance).

Comment: @user17732522 True, it's all implementation defined. But OP insists that this is not a purely theoretical problem. Practical problems require practical solutions. Such is the nature of the C language.

Comment: I guess to avoid implementation defined behavior, your C code would pass the beginning of the object and the size around, instead of two pointers.

Comment: is it conforming or not conforming? https://godbolt.org/z/6rWc8aeb4

Comment: @jxh True, and that’s exactly the approach the linked proposal takes, for example. Unfortunately, if the code in question needs to chomp off space from the beginning of the buffer and there is more than one such buffer (*e.g.* iconv), the bookkeeping starts getting *really annoying*. Not impossible, just annoying, in a place you want to be as straightforward as possible. (But I will admit this question is mostly morbid curiosity on my part.)

Comment: @AlexShpilkin Helper functions should remove much of the annoyance. However, you may need a full fledged data type to handle reference counting of multiple views pointing to different points of the same buffer.

Comment: @user17732522 ... I think it is? The point there is that if we know _begin_ and _end_ are as described and at least _len_ apart, we can safely test if they are at least 2 _len_ apart by comparing _begin_ + _len_ (which is known to be in the permissible range by the hypothesis) and _end_ − _len_ (ditto); so we start with (a separate test for _end_ > _begin_, then set) _len_ = 1 and work our way up. I don’t see any conformance problems here.

Comment: @AlexShpilkin Oops, yes, I did not read the answer correctly. OK, I didn't realize you could get `O(log n)` using the `<` ordering that way..