# Is it conforming or not. Object size calculatiuon using pointers of different types than the original object

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Inspired by: [Object size from (begin, end) pointers in strictly conforming C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071030/object-size-from-begin-end-pointers-in-strictly-conforming-c#71071030)

Is this function conforming or not?

```
//end always past start
size_t objsize(const void *restrict start, const void *restrict end)
{
    const unsigned long long * restrict s = start;
    const unsigned long long * restrict e = end;

    return sizeof(*s) * (size_t)(e - s);
}
```

Comment: Unless `start` and `end` in fact point to elements of the same array of `long long` (signed or unsigned), this is UB.

Comment: And even with the conditions satisfied, it is only _conforming_ (to some implementation), not _strictly conforming_, as asked in the other question, since it depends on the maximum value of `ptrdiff_t` relative to the maximum array size, as is the point of the linked question.

Comment: `in fact point to elements of the same array of long long` does it have to be `long long`? They could point to elements of the same array of some different type and be aligned to `long long`.

Comment: @KamilCuk _They could point to elements of the same array of some different type and be aligned to `long long`_ And what should be the result of `e - s` if, say, «some different type» has size is 2×`sizeof(long long)`, `start` points at the element with subscript 0 and `end` — with subsript 1?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _signed or unsigned_ Huh? What allows difference in signedness between an array element type and the pointed-to type of an expression participating in pointer arithmetic?

Comment: It depends if `e-s` fits to `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @tstanisl it should as  ptrdiff_t holds the difference in the units of unsigned long long. usually 8x smaller that the difference in `char`

Comment: yes.. but AFAIK the standard puts no restriction on width of `ptrdiff_t`. Theoretically, it could be even 17 bits (from https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.3p2)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object". A pointer of type "pointer to long long" can point to an object to type "unsigned long long" and vice versa, no problem here, these types have the same size and alignment.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. _A pointer of type "pointer to long long" can point to an object to type "unsigned long long" and vice versa_ What does «can point» mean? If an `int` object has alignment enough for `long long` and we cast pointer to it to `long long*`, does it point to the `int` object (when `sizeof(long long) == 2 * sizeof(int)`)? _no problem here, these types have the same size and alignment_ I can understand the alignment part because it affects casting. But where does "same size" come from? I don't see it in **6.5.6 Additive operators**.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p6

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. And? How does this affect pointer arithmetic? **6.5.6 Additive operators** doesn't have restrictions on the type of a pointer expression and the type of the pointed-to array element. Compare with https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.add#6.sentence-1. (Which, BTW, outlaws using a pointer to the corresponding (un)signed type, e.g. `int i; (unsigned*)&i + 0;` is UB, even though in C++ they also have the same size and alignment requirement)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "doesn't have restrictions on the type of a pointer expression and the type of the pointed-to array element" This looks like a defect to me, I'm too lazy to look up a corresponding defect report. C++ is a completely different language, irrelevant.